# Reference a form, change action url, then post it

Tags: jquery

In jquery, I need to reference a form, change the action url, then post it.

So I can get my form using the ID like:

```
$("#frmtest")
```

Now I want to change the action url, then post it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$("#frmtest").attr("action", myNewActionUrl).submit();
```